# Should my LDAP client application have option to use "ldaps" and/or "StartTLS"?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am writing a simple client to authenticate user via LDAP. I am using OpenLDAP libraries. The application simply searches for the user in the LDAP server and bind the user.

While configuring LDAP server (OpenLDAP) for [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html), I came across -

> LDAP over TLS/SSL (ldaps://) is deprecated in favour of StartTLS. The
>   latter refers to an existing LDAP session (listening on TCP port 389)
>   becoming protected by TLS/SSL whereas LDAPS, like HTTPS, is a distinct
>   encrypted-from-the-start protocol that operates over TCP port 636.

Does this mean that the LDAP client I am writing is OK not to have an option for selecting the encryption type? Is this deprecated?
Here is the wire-frame I am about to implement in couple of days:
[image]

Any thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: Just a thought: regardless of what you're reading, I do not agree that SSL is deprecated. StartTLS requires an additional operation which makes it less efficient than SSL from an LDAP client perspective. StartTLS is convenient, certainly, and useful, but it's presence as an option does not *deprecate* the use of SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you should use one of those types. It doesn't mean you need a UI option to select it.